# Are there any negatives to a self-standing putter?

Tags: equipment, golf

I have seen a few putters being made that are designed to stand up when placed on the green. I'm told this is done so the player can line the putter up and step back and check it out from a different angle.

The way this works is the putter head is heavy & the shaft is really light.

Besides the inflated price, are there any negatives to using a putter like this?

What affect will the unusually heavy head have on the putting motion?

Comment: What are you looking for here. You indicate you've already seen reviews. Scientific studies?